# How to make CRUD operations on a one to one or one to zero relation?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Am create an employee management system where there are two kinds of employees:

1. contract employee
2. permanent employee

the permanent has all the properties that the contract user has so i figured out a one to one or one to zero where i will have 2 models contractUser and PermanentUser and the contractUser may or may not have a record in the permanentUsers Table, I think everything is fine for the models but how can i add a permanentUser record to the contractUser here are the two models:

```
public class ContractUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "الاسم")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="من فضلك ادخل اسم الموظف")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "الرقم القومي")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "برجاء ادخال الرقم القومي")]
    [MaxLength(14,ErrorMessage ="الرقم القومي بجب ان يتكون من 14 رقم فقظ")]
    [MinLength(14, ErrorMessage = "الرقم القومي بجب ان يتكون من 14 رقم ")]
    public string nationalId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "رقم الموبيل")]
    [Required (ErrorMessage = "برجاء ادخال رقم الموبيل")]
    [MaxLength(11, ErrorMessage = "رقم الموبيل بجب ان يتكون من 11 رقم فقظ")]
    [MinLength(11, ErrorMessage = "رقم الموبيل بجب ان يتكون من 11 رقم ")]
    public string mobileNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "العنوان")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="برجاء ادخال العنوان")]
    public string address { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "نسبة العجز")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "برجاء ادخال نسبة العجز و ان كانت 0")]
    [Range(0,100,ErrorMessage ="بحب النسبة ان تكون بين 0-100")]
    public int disablityPrecentage { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "تاريخ الميلاد")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "برجاء ادخال تاريخ الميلاد")]
    public DateTime birthDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "تاريخ التعاقد")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "برجاء ادخال تاريخ التعاقد")]
    public DateTime contractionDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "الحالة الاجتماعية")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "  برجاءاختيار الحالة الاجتماعية ")]
    public int maritalStateId { get; set; }


    //navigation properties
    public MaritalState maritalState { get; set; }
    public PermanentUser permanentUserDetails { get; set; }
```

Permanent user Class

```
 public class PermanentUser
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("ContractUser")]
    public int EmpolyeeId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "براجاء ادخال المؤهل")]
    [Display(Name = "المؤهل")]
    public string Qualification { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "براجاء ادخال المسمي الوظيفي")]
    [Display(Name = "المسمي الوظيفي")]
    public string jobName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "براجاء ادخال رقم الملف ")]
    [Display(Name = "رقم ملف الخدمة")]
    public int fileNumber { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "براجاء ادخال تاريخ التثبيت  ")]
    [Display(Name = "تاريخ التثبيت ")]
    public DateTime tasbetDate { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "براجاء ادخال قرار التثبيت  ")]
    [Display(Name = "قرار التثبيت ")]
    public int tasbetOrderNumber { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "براجاء اختيار المجموعة الوظيفية  ")]
    [Display(Name = "المجموعة الوظيفية  ")]
    public int jobGroupId { get; set; }


    //navigation properties

    public ContractUser ContractUser { get; set; }
    public JobGroup jobGroup { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a Employee model with all the shared properties and then let the ContractUser and PermanentUser model inherit from the Employee model.

Entity framework Core creates a single table in the database, this Table has all the properties so you don't have to link the two models.